# $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ differentiable function s.t. $|f'(x)| \le 100$ for all $x \in \mathbb R$. Prove $f$ uniformly continuous.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, proof-writing, uniform-continuity

> Let $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be a differentiable function such that $|f'(x)| \le 100$ for all $x \in \mathbb R$. Prove that $f$ is uniformly continuous.

I don't know how to start this proof. I know the proof is going to have the following reasoning somewhere in the proof but I am having trouble putting the pieces together:

If we use the mean value theorem, then we have
$$\left| \frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}\right|=\left| f'(c) \right| \le 100.$$

So,
$$\left| \frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}\right| \le 100.$$
Which implies
$$|f(b)-f(a)|\le 100|b-a| < 100 \delta.$$

So, if we let $100\delta =\epsilon$, then we can use $\delta= \epsilon /100$ in the definition of uniform continuity.

However, I am having trouble in the beginning part of the proof. How do I use $|x-x_0| < \delta$ in the mean value theorem? Or maybe I need to use $|x-x_0| < \delta$ after I use mean value theorem?

I am having trouble because MVT is stated in terms of a closed interval. How do I work in this closed interval to invoke MVT in the proof?

Answer (score 1):

Your reasoning is almost going through: $|f(x)-f(y)|\leq 100|x-y|<100\delta=\epsilon$ whenever $|x-y|<\delta=\epsilon/100$.

Here are the proper steps: Fix an $\epsilon>0$, for every $x,y$ with $|x-y|<\epsilon/100$, then there exists some $\eta_{x,y}$ lies in between $x$ and $y$ such that $|f(x)-f(y)|=|f'(\xi_{x,y})||x-y|$, so $|f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon$.

Comment: That's what I wrote

Comment: My question is about, how do I choose a neighborhood to invoke the mean value theorem?

Comment: Then you are done! Note that you cannot fix an $x_{0}$, because you are going to prove uniform continuity.

Comment: But I need to choose a neighborhood of $x_0$, then say $|x-x_0| \implies$... So, how do I choose a neighborhood, then use MVT?

Comment: No, you cannot choose a neighbourhood depending on $x_{0}$, this is not the definition of uniform continuity.

Comment: Uniform continuity says: for all $\epsilon$ there exists $\delta$ such that for all $x, x_0$, $|x-x_0| < \delta \implies |f(x)-f(x_0)| < \epsilon$.

Comment: That is, for all $x$ in a $\delta$ neighborhood of $x_0$, all $f(x)$ are in a $\epsilon$ neighborhood of $f(x_0)$.

Comment: I recommend not to write $x_{0}$, this is misleading. Anyway, so from your definition, you can already see that such a $\delta>0$ is independent of the variable $x$ and $y$.

Comment: We want to specify an $x_0$ because we want to look at $|x-x_0|<\delta$ as a $\delta$ neighborhood of $x_0$.

Comment: No, you don't want to specify $x_0$. Statement is, whenever $|x-y|<\delta$, then $|f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon$.

Comment: And such a $\delta>0$ depends only on $\epsilon$. Anyway, so in this case you can take $\delta$ to be $\epsilon/100$, so such a $\delta$ really depends on $\epsilon$ only.

Comment: Yes, that is saying $y-\delta<x<y+\delta$. In essence, a neighborhood of $y$.

Comment: Then by choosing $\delta$ to be $\epsilon/100$, for every $y$, take the neighbourhood as a ball centred at $y$ with radius $\epsilon/100$ still makes $|f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon$ going true whenever $x$ is in the neighbourhood.